# Minimum required data for cosine fit

Tags: optimization, regression

With a minimum amount of (noisy) data-points, I need to find the amplitude of a simple cosine $y=A*cos(x)$, where x is an angle from $0$:$2\pi$.

I know how to fit data to the function, and I know how to find the goodness of fit.

However, I receive my data over time, in random order. I want to minimize the 'gathering' time. Therefore, I am trying to define a bound that determines that I have received enough data to make a reasonable fit.

For example, I cannot simply set a bound on the number of data-points, as you could do for a linear function. This is because the data that corresponds to $x = 0.5\pi$, $x=1.5\pi$ are useless ($y(x) =0$), while data corresponding to $x=0$, $x=\pi$ are very useful ($y(x)=A$). Not just the amount of data matters, also its $x$-location.

What is a good metric that relates my data to how well the amplitude of a cosine can be found?

Comment: Is your $x$ really time so that you receive data in increasing order of $x$? And the frequency is not variable?

Comment: No, x is an angle, I receive my data in random order of x.

Comment: What model can be assumed for the noise?

Comment: The noise varies with the angle x, according to B*cos(x), where B is a normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how useful will be my answer. I assume here that your objective is to minimize the sum of squares of the absolute errors on $Y$'s. Then, I suppose that, for the optimum $A$ parameter, you use $A = S_1 / S_2$, in which $S_1$ is the sum of $y(i)\cos[x(i)]$ and $S_2$ is the sum of $\cos^2[x(i)]$; the summations run from $i=1$ to $i=N$.

If you acquire a new data point, you just need to add $y(N+1)\cos[x(N+1)]$ to $S_1$ to update this quantity and to add $\cos^2[x(N+1)]$ to $S_2$ to update this other quantity. So, very few operations are required every time you add one data point.

Since this procedure is very inexpensive, I should not worry about the number of points and I should not discard any data point since, at the same time, each point is in error and brings information.

Comment: I assume that you advice to minimise S1/S2? By dividing S1 by S2, I obtain y(i)/cos([x(i)], correct? In that case (S1/S2) goes to infinity when x=0.5pi and x=1.5pi. If the goal is to minimise S1/S2, then adding more data is always unwanted. Also, in this case S1/S2 seems to be dependent on the amplitude that I want to find.

Comment: Not at all. Sorry for not using LateX (I am almost blind). S1 is Sum[y(i)*Cos[x(i)],i=1 to N] and S2 is Sum[Cos[x(i)]^2,i=1 to N]. The ratio of these two sums (S1 / S2) is the optimum value of A (assuming that you want to minimize the sum of squares of absolute errors on the y's. Tell me if this is more clear.

Comment: @Raskolnikov. Thanks for editing. Merry Xmax !

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't though about this way of finding the optimum value of A. It is much more elegant than a nonlinear least square fit. However, it doesn't answer my question of how to determine when to stop gathering data (the gathering-time must be minimised). But I guess I can stop whenever an additional data-point  does not significantly affect the value of A anymore, right?

Comment: @user117490. The formula I gave you is the solution of the linear least square problem (your model is linear with resêct to A). For the remaining of your question, it is difficult to me to provide a definitive answer since each data point is rich in information. What you can do is to follow the value of A as a function of the number of data points (remember that for one new data point you just update S1 and S2).